# How has the social impact of the scifi classic Star Wars affected real world technology?

Tags: star-wars, influences

A lot of us have probably heard about people that [Star Trek inspired](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_William_Shatner_Changed_the_World) to get into high tech jobs, and even (pre?)invent some of the devices(like [communicators](http://www.starstore.com/acatalog/st-os-communicator.jpg)) depicted on the TV series. Is there an example (excluding the obvious advances in special effects) of something beneficial to our current average citizen in todays world that was a result of something seen in a Star Wars film?

Comment: This hasn't helped: http://www.dailytech.com/George+Lucas+Angry+About+Real+Life+Lightsaber+Threatens+to+Sue/article18964.htm

Comment: What I mean is, unlike ST, Lucas' team get sue happy when anyone does anything even tangential to "his" stuff.

Comment: Jar-Jar Binks' patented fruit retrieval technology?

Comment: I'm tempted to VTC since "inspired" is a little ill-defined. Do you mind being a bit more precise please?

Comment: @DVK I edited to avoid that (thanks for the heads up). I thought I'd covered my bases by citing How Star Trek Changed the World.

Comment: @MajorStackings - does "Spaceballs" count as "beneficial"?

Comment: Well, not yet.. but as soon as the Kickstarter for my Death Star gets funded...

Comment: I daresay we'd have no toy lightsabers without Star Wars. Given that toy lightsabers in various states of disrepair form about 80% of the clutter where young male humans reside, I'd say that is a major domestic technology.

Comment: Let's not forget the Dykstraflex Camera and THX Digital Sound. Both arising from the tech base for the series' production.

Comment: Sorry, Major: I edited this in the hope it'd get reopened, but apparently [the community is against it](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/78983) :-(

Answer (score 0):

My first job out of college was an engineer on a [Star Wars or SDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategic_Defense_Initiative) project. The project used adaptive optics, which is now used in many ground based telescopes.

Comment: That's kind of a stretch. Star Wars was a nick name for the project, but if you can make a good case by explaining how the movie shakes hands with the adaptive optics used in the SDI (beyond the fact the project borrowed the movies name), I would accept it.

Comment: Most of the examples quoted in the tv show "How William Shatner Changed the World" which was given as the main example in your question, were I watched on the the Star Trek Series and decided to go into a high tech field. We decided to build a Death Star.  As to the impact of the Program, some historians credit it with ending the Cold War and Soviet Union.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep - the question isn't the impact of SDI, it's what specific inspiration for the idea came from "Star Wars" movie **other** than the program's nickname. Certainly, the idea of space based weapons wasn't first raised by Lucas