# Are there intellectual advantages that favor viewing star trek

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9

Is it culturally pertinent to the extent that it'd duly attract scholarly recognition. Do both TOS, TNG, DS9 fit the rule for this? Have the shows inspired modern scientists of the current time to enter the field?? If so, how can this be quantifiably measurated [as in the overall impact gauged]. (More detail: That the filmed series is not primarily intended for the general television enthusiast; relevance extending beyond the main layperson audience.)

Comment: [Star Trek Studies](http://courses.georgetown.edu/?CourseID=PHIL-180)

Comment: Basically a dupe of this (closed) question; http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12267/how-has-the-social-impact-of-the-scifi-classic-star-wars-affected-real-world-tec

Comment: TIL: I want to audit that class from Georgetown

Comment: Hi Quendzdlophus, welcome to SFF Stack Exchange! Unfortunately I and several others couldn't work out what your question is really asking. If you [edit] it to make it a bit clearer, it might be worth reopening.

Comment: @Richard Er, what? Did you mix up Star Wars and Star Trek?! What an embarrassing mistake, especially for the only person with gold tag badges in both ;-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Substitute whichever iconic scifi series you want, it's still way too broad to be sensibly answered.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - And no, I didn't mix them up. Hence "*basically*" :-P

Comment: @Richard OK, if you say so :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor - [Oh, a wise guy, eh?](http://media.giphy.com/media/pEP4CwhG1f1uw/giphy.gif)

Comment: @Richard The suppressed smile at the end of that fist-shake says it all.

Answer (score 3):

## Certainly, Star Trek has inspired people to pursue careers in science

You ask, "Have the shows inspired modern scientists of the current time to enter the field??"  The answer is most certainly **yes**.

Concrete examples:

- **Astrophysicist Candy Torres** cites Star Trek as one of the reasons she became a scientist (read more [here](http://www.cnn.com/2011/IREPORT/07/06/torres.shuttle.irpt/index.html))

> Weaned on the vision of an enlightened spacefaring society that "Star Trek" offered, and inspired by President John F. Kennedy's call to put an American on the moon, Torres dedicated herself at an early age to working in the space program.
>
> "It was easy to aspire to a future like that where people got along regardless of race or religion, just because they were human. Being a lifelong 'Star Trek' fan made me see the space program not just as sci-fi, but as a positive vision of the future, at a time when we desperately needed those positive visions."

- **Novelist R.C. Davison**, author of *Orbital Maneuvers*, pursued a **degree in physics** because of Star Trek and Mr. Spock in particular (read more [here](http://orbitalmaneuvers.com/author.html))

> TV offered a few programs that were on during the time I was allowed to watch it:  Twilight Zone (Scared me.), Outer Limits (Scared me even more!), Lost in Space (Wanted to be part of the Robinson family.), Voyage to the Bottom of the Sea (Interesting, but every week it was a new monster trying to destroy the sub.), Land of the Giants (Didn’t get to watch this one too much.) and the one that blew them all away—Star Trek! (Ahhh!)  The technology, the characters and the special effects mesmerized me. (Yes, special effects.  Don’t laugh!  Taken in the context of TV sci-fi programs in the sixties, Star Trek was a quantum leap above the rest.)
>
> I found myself particularly fascinated with Mr. Spock—the pure intellect, the cool, emotionless logic and the apparent mastery of everything having to do with science and math.  Mr. Spock was my inspiration to pursue a career in the sciences.  Star Trek, coupled with the fervor growing with the Apollo Space Program, and the goal of landing on the Moon by the end of the decade, fueled my desire to be out there exploring The Final Frontier.

- **Professor Philip Kesten** of Santa Clara University was inspired to become a physicist by Star Trek and now teaches a "Physics of Star Trek" course at the University (read more [here](http://www.startrek.com/article/how-star-trek-changed-my-life-dr-philip-kesten))

> “What we’re doing in the Physics of Star Trek is literally peeling back a little piece of science that seems interesting and seeing how deeply we can go into it. I started the term by looking at the solar system and then the galaxy and the universe, because, hey, what is Star Trek really about? It’s going where no man has gone before. So, what’s out there? And once we understand what’s out there we can understand why we want to go there and how we’re going to get there. So that led me to look at, say, the development of warp drive. But if you don’t understand how far away Vulcan is, why would you care about warp drive? So it all has to hang together. It has to hang together the same way a Star Trek story does, and I’m telling them a story, essentially.”

Comment: (I won't put this in the answer, but I myself had been driven by Star Trek towards a science career....)

Comment: same thing here :)

Comment: Absolutely! It's worth noting that NASA recently commisioned a design for ISX Enterprise (In honour, and inspired by Star Trek's USS Enterprise) which you can read about here http://www.theverge.com/2014/6/13/5806104/nasas-warp-drive-spaceship-concept-enterprise

Comment: @Praxis I think that this answer needs you to add yourself!  You're a very important person and deserve to be on the answer! 

Comment: @N_Soong : Only if you are added as well --- I may be wrong, but I suspect your particular cocktail of uni courses has been influenced at least somewhat by Star Trek.  :-)

Comment: @Praxis Actually it was inspired by *The Bob Newhart Show*; my personal interests in programming though were primarily inspired by *Star Trek*

Comment: Candy Torres is actually B'Elanna's ancestor, right?